# Calling function using 'new' is less expensive than without it?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, prototypal-inheritance

Given this very familiar model of prototypal construction:

```
function Rectangle(w,h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}
Rectangle.prototype.area = function() { 
    return this.width * this.height;
};
```

Can anyone explain why calling `new Rectangle(2,3)` is consistently 10x FASTER than calling `Rectangle(2,3)` without the 'new' keyword? I would have assumed that because new adds more complexity to the execution of a function by getting prototypes involved, it would be slower.

Example:

```
var myTime;
function startTrack() {
    myTime = new Date();
}
function stopTrack(str) {
    var diff = new Date().getTime() - myTime.getTime();
    println(str + ' time in ms: ' + diff);
}

function trackFunction(desc, func, times) {
    var i;
    if (!times) times = 1;
    startTrack();
    for (i=0; i<times; i++) {
        func();
    }
    stopTrack('(' + times + ' times) ' + desc);
}

var TIMES = 1000000;

trackFunction('new rect classic', function() {
    new Rectangle(2,3);
}, TIMES);

trackFunction('rect classic (without new)', function() {
    Rectangle(2,3);
}, TIMES);
```

Yields (in Chrome):

> ```
> (1000000 times) new rect classic time in ms: 33
> (1000000 times) rect classic (without new) time in ms: 368
>
> (1000000 times) new rect classic time in ms: 35
> (1000000 times) rect classic (without new) time in ms: 374
>
> (1000000 times) new rect classic time in ms: 31
> (1000000 times) rect classic (without new) time in ms: 368
> ```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you call the function without "new", what is it that you suspect "this" is pointing to?  It'll be "window."  Updating that is slower than updating the freshly-built new object you'll be using when you invoke it with "new".

Change the second version to this:

```
trackFunction('rect classic (without new)', function() {
    Rectangle.call({}, 2,3);
}, TIMES);
```

and see what you get. Another thing to try would be this:

```
trackFunction('rect with constant object', (function() {
  var object = { height: 0, width: 0 };
  return function() {
    Rectangle.call(object, 2, 3);
  };
})());
```

That will save on the cost of rebuilding the dummy object on each iteration.

Comment: When I do that above, I get around 148 ms execution on the new object. Not as fast as calling new, but much faster than touching the document.

Comment: Right - also note that in the second version there's the overhead of calling the "call" function too. I suspect that V8 has a pretty well-optimized implementation of "new" (in fact that's pretty clear from your numbers)!

Comment: Also note that Rectangle(2,3) does not actually create anything, it simply (tries) to update the window height and width

Comment: And neither does Rectangle.call({}, 2,3) for that matter. So not sure how valid these comparisons are

Comment: It doesn't create anything, but it has something other than "window" for the "this" pointer to reference. Actually I'll update the answer with another idea. Oh, and note, @Angus, that it **does** create something - the empty object that's the first argument of "call".

Comment: @Pointy: but the empty object is never returned (unlike the implicit `return this` present in all `new` invocations).

Comment: True, but that's not really what the original question was worrying about. Since (presumably) it's *more* work to return something, and the topic under investigation is why the "new" version is already *faster*, I don't see why making the non-"new" invocation return something would be of interest.  The OP is certainly free to add a return statement, of course.